# create the variable's name after take off within a loop

Tags: tcl, expect

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set a1 "aaa"
set a2 "bbb"
set a3 "ccc"

for {set b 1} {$b<4} {incr b} {
   send a$b
}
```

The output is :

```
 a1a2a3
```

Looks like instead of values for

```
$a1
$a2
$a3
```

all we got was the actual names of the "variables" which is

```
a1
a2
a3
```

let's try this code:

```
send $$b
```

now the output is

```
$1$2$3
```

which means if we can get the letter `a` sneaked into there.. we can create

```
$a1
$a2
$a3
```

How can i sneak the letter "a" in to there ?

after that i need to do something like..

```
$c = $$b
send $c
```

which means those values become $c
and then i can execute the $c with `send`.

but

```
 $c = $$b
```

is not working. and neither does.

```
 set c = $$b
```

or

```
c=$$b
```

ultimately the goal is to print the values for

```
$a1 and $a2 and $a3
```

some recommended arrays and lists, but they seem to be either not orderly
or not organized so i can easily edit $a1, $a2, $a3, etc. ( by hand )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with lists or arrays...

But you're asking for this:

```
eval "puts \$a$b"
```

But still, `list` is meant exactly for that task, use it.

Edit:
Seems like the right way to do it is:

```
puts [set a$b]
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically, when you're doing something like this you're actually best off using an array.

```
set a(1) "aaa"
set a(2) "bbb"
set a(3) "ccc"

for {set b 1} {$b<4} {incr b} {
     send $a($b)
}
```

This is because the parsing rules for array element names are those for general strings, and not for the very restricted subset that are variable-names-following-`$`.

Answer (score 0):

Only one round of variable substitution is done, but command substitutions can be nested so you need to use a command. With only one argument, [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/set.htm) just returns the value of the variable with that name (in early Tcl versions there were no `$variable` substitutions, you *had to* use `[set variable]`).

```
set a 100
set b "a"
set c "b"
puts [set [set [set c]]]
puts [set [set $c]] ;# same result
```

But don't use the `set` trick for indexing. Tcl already has arrays and dictionarys (Tcl 8.5 and later) that index with any string, and lists that index with integers, and that's faster.

```
set a [list "aaa" "bbb" "ccc"]
for {set b 0} {$b <= 2} {incr b} {
  send [lindex $a $b]
}
```